# How to pass the third parameter from the login form to authenticate the user

Tags: php, yii

Hi I am using the third field in the login form my login form code look like this

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php   echo $form->labelEx($model,'userrole'); ?>
    <?php 
        $data = Userrole::model()->findAll();
        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'userrole', CHtml::listData($data, 'id', 'userType'));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'userrole'); ?>
</div>
```

here i should pass the third parameter to authenticate the user so how to pass to the UserIdentity class. UserIdentity class defined only username, password attributes so it will get only the username and password so, how to get the third one

Comment: Show us your model rules.  For reference, you may want to read up on [Declaring Validation Rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules).

Answer (score 2):

[The constructor in CUserIdentity is just a setter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUserIdentity#__construct-detail). So you could make the following changes to pass userole to CUserIdentity

1) Update your Form (I'm assuming it's LoginForm?)
    public $userrole;

Then in your authenticate method, update the call to UserIdentity to include the userrole

```
$this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password, $this->userrole);
```

Then in in your UserIdentity.php file, add the following:

```
public $userrole;
public function __construct($username, $password, $userrole)
{
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->userrole = $userrole;
}
```

You might have to tweak it a little, but that's the general gist of what you'd need to do to pass the variable up. Make sure you update your Form::rules() array so userrole is properly validated.